# Help Center: I took the "2 minute tour" ages ago, why does the system ask me to take it again?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

Irrespective of the fact that I have taken the tour, help center shows me the banner to take the "2 minute tour".

<sup>(In hushed voice) And I have repeatedly taken it few times after that just because there's a big banner in help center.</sup>

Would not it be good if we could remove it from the help center, once they have visited it? There is no need to add yet another flag to the system. Merely checking the existence of [**Informed**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) badge will do.

Alternatively, rather than removing we can push it to the bottom of the page.

Comment: You're *supposed* to read it every day. Aloud. With your hand over your heart.

Comment: Shog is just kidding. Seriously now, you're supposed to know all the information in the Help Center by heart, so there wouldn't be any need to visit it at all.

Comment: I wouldn't relate having the "informed" badge with somebody _actually_ being informed about everything in the "about page"...

Comment: @Tanner - neither would I, but how else would you decide whether or not to show the banner? (Assuming that is, that you didn't want to show the banner *all* the time).

Comment: @ChrisF It was a tongue in cheek comment, but you could base it on reputation and user status. If a user has negative actions against them, like down votes, close votes and all the other things that might flag a user for warnings then they see it. If however, they are a model citizen past a certain rep threshold, it is hidden or collapsed.

Comment: What are you doing in the help center anyway?

Comment: @canon Looking up a privilege, or looking up a particular site's on-topic page, or looking up a help center page whose URL to provide to a less experienced user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, whatever the original intent was here, only about 0.39% of registered users ever clicked through to the tour... So as of July 7th, the banner isn't shown to registered users at all.

#### See also: [Help Center header seems to have gone missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298524/help-center-header-seems-to-have-gone-missing)